# marshmallow_dataclass - subclassing builtin types

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I'm using marshmallow dataclasses to type check a file available as a dictionary.
In the file there are some special number triplets, which specify (typ, min, max) values.
I want to validate and store this values in special classes, subclassing python's Tuple.
However, I get an ValidationError all the time:

Here's a MWE

```py
from typing import Any, Tuple, List
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass

data = {'key1': (1, 2, 3),
        'key2': (2, 3, 4)}

@dataclass
class Triplet(Tuple[int, int, int]):
    pass

    def someCalculation(self):
        pass

@dataclass
class Triplet2(List):
    pass

    def someCalculation(self):
        pass



@dataclass
class MySchema:
    key1: Tuple[int, int, int]
    key2: Triplet

schema = MySchema.Schema().load(data)
print(schema)
```

I already tried subclassing List and Tuple, but none of my attempts works as expected.
Is there a way to use my Triplet class?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I found out the `pre_load` decorator of `marshmallow` is able to suit my needs.

In this function I return a dictionary with the keys I want, so the Triplet class is instanciated correctly

```py
from typing import Any, Tuple, List
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass
from marshmallow import pre_load

data = {'key1': (1, 2, 3),
        'key2': (2, 3, 4)}

@dataclass
class Triplet:
    typ: float
    min: float
    max: float

    @pre_load
    def preprocess(self, data, **kwargs):
        return {'typ': data[0], 'min': data[1], 'max': data[2]}

    def someCalculation(self):
        pass
    
@dataclass
class MySchema:
    key1: Tuple[int, int, int]
    key2: Triplet

schema = MySchema.Schema().load(data)
print(schema)
```